# How do I find the maximum and minimum values of the function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I find the maximum and minimum values of the function

$$ f(x,y) = \sin x\sin y\sin(x+y).$$

The correct answer given is $\max(\pi/3,\pi/3)$ and $\min(-\pi/3,-\pi/3)$.

I just don't have the necessary intuition to arrive at this answer.

I'm only stuck at solving the simultaneous questions.

Please suggest guidelines.

I'm stuck at solving the simultaneous equations below.

\begin{equation*} f(x,y) = \sin x \sin y \sin(x+y) \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= \sin y\sin(2x+y)=0
\end{equation*}

and

\begin{equation*} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= \sin y \sin(2y+x)=0 \end{equation*}

Need to find the critical points.

Comment: Hi, welcome.  Please fill in the work you've done up until the point you're stuck and we can help you get unstuck.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Do check the edited question.

Comment: Your calculation for $f_y$ is incorrect. It should be $\sin x \sin (x+2y)$? Now depending on domain of $x, y$, find critical points. One is clearly $(0, 0)$. You also have $x+2y = 0, 2x+y = \pi$, vice versa or both of them as $\pi$.

Comment: @MathLover Sorry typo. Do you have a solution to propose?

Comment: $$ 2x+y = npi $$ precisely?

Comment: I already mentioned. For example, how would you solve system of equations $2x+y=\pi$ and $x+2y = \pi$? Multiply the first by $2$ and subtract second from first. You get $x = \frac{\pi}{3}, y = \frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: yes you are right. That is why I said it depends on the domain. If not given, the general solution will be to take $x+2y = m \pi, 2x+y = n \pi$

Comment: So from your standpoint, if there are infinitely many critical points, for how many of them will one need to check to get the minimum and the maximum?

Comment: @MathLover Can you elaborate on how you got
$x+2y=0, 2x+y=pi$

Comment: @Moo Yup, the answer is what's given in the book, but no step by step solution was provided on how to arrive at those values and that's what I actually need, the main one being how to solve the equations simultaneously.

Comment: @Math Lover When equating $\sin x \sin (x+2y)=0$, we get $ sinx=0 $ or $ sin(x+2y)=0$ $=> x=mπ$ or $x+2y = nπ$, what made you choose n=1?

Comment: @user3187800 I did not choose. I gave you an example. If the domain is restricted, you work with that otherwise you work with $n$ and $m$. You can still solve the system of equations, exactly the way I mentioned in my example. You may not get the exact book answer unless the question restricted the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will need to put some partial derivatives on the table, as well as Hessian matrix, which is used for [investigating critical points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test)!:

\begin{align}
f_x &= \sin(y) \sin(2x+y) \\
f_y &= \sin(x) \sin(x+2y) \\
f_{xx} &= \sin(2x+2y) - \sin(2x) \\
f_{xy} &= f_{yx} = \sin(2x+2y) \\
f_{yy} &= \sin(2x+2y) - \sin(2y),
\end{align}
the Hessian matrix
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    f_{xx} & f_{xy}\\
    f_{yx }& f_{yy}\\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

As we have established basic partial derivatives, it is time to put them to equation, as we are searching for critical values of the function (these values will be further investigated and as we will see, not all of them are extrema of function $f$).

Consider $k \in \mathbb{Z}$:

$$f_x = 0 \implies \sin(y) \sin(2x+y) = 0$$
$$f_y = 0 \implies \sin(x) \sin(x+2y) = 0$$
For the first equation we have
$$y = k\pi$$
$$\lor$$
$$2x+y = 0 \Leftrightarrow y = -2x + k\pi.$$

Plugging the $y = k\pi$ to second equation, we have
$$ \sin(x) \sin(x+2k\pi) = 0$$
that gives us again two values:
$$x = 0$$
$$\lor$$
$$x+2k\pi = 0 \Leftrightarrow x=-2k\pi + k\pi.$$
Sendind $x$ back to $y = k\pi$, we receive two critical points:
$$[0; k\pi], [-k\pi; k\pi]$$

Plugging the $y = -2x + k\pi$ to second equation, we have
$$ \sin(x) \sin(x - 4x + 2k\pi) = 0$$
$$- \sin(x) \sin(3x - 2k\pi) = 0$$
that will, as "always", give us two values:
$$x = 0$$
$$\lor$$
$$3x - 2k\pi = 0 \Leftrightarrow 3x = 2k\pi  - k\pi.$$
$$3x = k\pi \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{k\pi}{3}$$
Sendind $x$ back to $y = -2x + k\pi$, we receive two critical points:
$$\left[\frac{k\pi}{3}; \frac{k\pi}{3}\right], [0; k\pi]$$

We have estabilished four critical values (yet we do not know if they are extrema) and we shall proceede with calculating determinant (more likely their positiveness, negativeness) as for matrix composed only of $f_{xx}$ as well as for Hessian matrix listed above.

Let $k = 0, 1, 2$ (clearly, these values are chosen purposely as the sine function reaches the zero value in three points: $0, \pi, 2\pi$):

For a point $\left[\frac{k\pi}{3}; \frac{k\pi}{3}\right]: $
$$[0, 0] \implies H(f)(0, 0)
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & ..\\
    .. & ..\\
  \end{pmatrix}
,$$
$$\left[\frac{\pi}{3}; \frac{\pi}{3}\right] \implies H(f)(\frac{\pi}{3}; \frac{\pi}{3}) 
\begin{pmatrix}
    -\sqrt{3} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}}\\
    -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}} & -\sqrt{3}\\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$$$\left[\frac{2\pi}{3}; \frac{2\pi}{3}\right] \implies H(f)(\frac{\pi}{3}; \frac{\pi}{3}) 
\begin{pmatrix}
    \sqrt{3} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}}\\
    \frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}} & \sqrt{3}\\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
According to second partial derivative test, we conclude that $\left[\frac{\pi}{3}; \frac{\pi}{3}\right]$ is the local maximum and $\left[\frac{2\pi}{3}; \frac{2\pi}{3}\right]$ is local minimum. Recalling that sine function should keep the same output in some periodicity, we can rewrite $\left[\frac{2\pi}{3}; \frac{2\pi}{3}\right]$ into $\left[-\frac{\pi}{3}; -\frac{\pi}{3}\right]$ as we substracted $\pi$ from both coordinates.

I have not showed the steps for $[0; k\pi], [-k\pi; k\pi]$, but you can rest assured that these critical points are saddles at best.

However, as mentioned above and in comments, the function is "self-repeating", therefore we can expect more than one correct answer :).